# How to echo an empty space (placeholder of sorts) when user input is not entered in certain fields

Tags: php, isset

I want to stop the size names from echoing if the input field for that certain size is not entered?

I would like to render an empty space for `<li>` where there was no quantity entered (in order to keep the same `<li>` format).

```
<?php

$mlv101207bkxs = $_POST['mlv101207bkxs'];
$mlv101207bksm = $_POST['mlv101207bksm'];
$mlv101207bkmd = $_POST['mlv101207bkmd'];
$mlv101207bklg = $_POST['mlv101207bklg'];
$mlv101207bkxl = $_POST['mlv101207bkxl'];
$mlv101207bkxxl = $_POST['mlv101207bkxxl'];

if(isset($_POST['mlv101207bkxs'],
         $_POST['mlv101207bksm'],
         $_POST['mlv101207bkmd'],
         $_POST['mlv101207bklg'],
         $_POST['mlv101207bkxl'],
         $_POST['mlv101207bkxxl'] )){    

echo "<p>Thank you for your order!</p>";

echo "<ul><h3>Ordered Items Below</h3>";

echo "<li>" . $mlv101207bkxs .  "&nbsp; -&nbsp; X-Small" . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $mlv101207bksm . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; Small" . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $mlv101207bkmd . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; Medium" . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $mlv101207bklg . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; Large" . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $mlv101207bkxl . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; X-Large" . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $mlv101207bkxxl . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; XX-Large" . "</li>";

echo "</ul>";
}
?>
    <form action="add_to_cart.php" method="post" name="orderform1" class="margins">
<a href="images/styles/large/mh800bk_big.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="thumb_align" src="images/styles/thumbs/mh800bk_thumb.jpg" /></a>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr class="gridaddrows">
<td colspan=8 class="radius">
<span class="formtext"><b>You must click the "Add to Cart" button to place items in cart.</b></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridrows">
<td class="gridtitle">Style</td>
<td class="gridtitle">XS</td>
<td class="gridtitle">S</td>
<td class="gridtitle">M</td>
<td class="gridtitle">L</td>
<td class="gridtitle">XL</td>
<td class="gridtitle">2XL</td>
</tr>
<td class="add_to_cart_btn">
<input type="image" src="http://taketwodesigns.com/shop6/images/addtocart.gif" alt="Add to Cart" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="mlv101207bkxs" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="mlv101207bksm" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="mlv101207bkmd" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="mlv101207bklg" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="mlv101207bkxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="mlv101207bkxxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: if no quantity  is ordered why have the line at all?

Comment: Your question is unclear and the example you provide includes JavaScript code that you don't show.  I also wonder why you check if all fields are set in one pass if you want some to be optional.

Comment: Julie, It only uses PHP and I don't really know the best way to make this code work most efficient... I am learning here though. :) I only need to display the ordered quantities, I just want to keep the format of the on the processed page for easy printing.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check for empty fields you can use a code similar to this

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }
```

Comment: Dhaval, thanks, but I don't really want to show required error, just have it process and show nothing for quantity ordered( not even 0 )

Comment: the $nameErr was an example , you can put any code that you want to have processed on that condition..